# AWS DynamoDB Trigger identifier needed that is equal across all invoked Lambdas. Preferably UUID

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

We're looking for a way to identify trigger invocations across multiple lambdas. That is, we need some sort of ID to get a reference, a link between two or more lambdas that are all invoked by the same trigger (which in our case is a DynamoDB event). It seems like `aws_request_id` might work here but the AWS documentation is not clear about whether it is equal across all lambdas invoked by the event trigger or not.

What we're currently doing is hashing the `event` object. I find that ugly because I'd rather have a real UUID (which `aws_request_id` appears to be) instead of a hash.

Is there some UUID identifier somewhere in `event` or `context` variables that are handed to the `lambda_handler` that we could use?

**Update 1:** It might be an option to use MD5 for hashing the `event` because it already has 128bits and can be directly turned into a UUID format. But that still involves hashing the event object. If there is already an ID somewhere that does not require additional calculations, we'll rather use that.

Comment: What is the higher-level goal you are wishing to accomplish by doing this? There might be a better way to achieve that goal, if you can tell us what you are wanting to accomplish.

Comment: The higher goal is to have a correlation ID that is reused in all involved components of a processing chain consisting of several AWS components. We need a correlation ID that we can use to combine log entries and explicitly correlate them to a distinct processing run and filter for single runs over all components. Example: a DynamoDB gets a new entry and triggers multiple Lambdas, one of them writes to an RDS and sends a message over SNS/SQS to an EC2 instance, which itself writes to another DynDB and so on. The logs of a single entity running through this chain must be correlatable.

Comment: Where exactly do you find this `aws_request_id`?  I don't see it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html) and AWS tends to use camelCase rather than snake_case (much to my chagrin, I find camel extremely difficult to read).

Comment: It's a field of the `context` (the 2nd positional argument) object handed to the lambda handler method. See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context.html